# iPhone and iPad not showing / not getting API response for client side rendering in next js app

Tags: iphone, next.js, safari, server-side-rendering, client-side-rendering

iPhone and iPad not showing / not getting API response for next js app.
UI not showing data for **client-side rendering**. But showing data for server-side rendering successfully.
This issue is happening on iPhone and iPad only. Mac, Windows, and Android are working perfectly.